# Automatic date when specific cell contains text "YES"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for help with this code:

```
function onEdit() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if( s.getName() == "Trip Overview" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet

    var r = s.getActiveCell();

    if( r.getColumn() == 12 ) { //checks the column

      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 15);

      //if( nextCell.getValue() !==  ) //is empty?

      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

The code is currently adding a date if column 12 contains ANY value, 1,2,3 or "Yes", "adf", "No" etc.

How to modify this code to only add a date if cell 12 contains "YES"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking if you are in the correct sheet and column, you need to check if the value of the cell is "YES"

```
function onEdit() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if( s.getName() == "Trip Overview" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet

    var r = s.getActiveCell();

    if( r.getColumn() == 12 ) { //checks the column

      if(r.getValue() == "YES") { //checksthe value of the cell

        var nextCell = r.offset(0, 15);

        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: In an `onEdit()` function, you should really make use of the EVENT provided as a parameter to the function, instead of calling `getActiveCell()`, to avoid unexpected results when a user has moved to a different location than the one that triggered the `onEdit()`.